Beauville exposé on K3 surfaces (notation clarification)
I'm having some trouble understanding the following notation (for reference, p. 117 in Beauville's géométrie des surfaces k3: modules et périodes).
Let $X, X$' be K3 surfaces. We consider a class $c \in H^4(X\times X', \mathbb{C})$ and define a homomorphism from $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ to $H^2(X',\mathbb{C})$ as
$$\alpha \mapsto (\operatorname{pr}_2)_*(c.\operatorname{pr}_1^*\alpha),$$
where $\operatorname{pr}_1, \operatorname{pr}_2$ are the projection on the first and second component resp.
What exactly does this map do? I mean, $\alpha \in H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ is sent to $\operatorname{pr}_1^*\alpha \in H^2(X\times X', \mathbb{C})$. Then, I guess, $(c.\operatorname{pr}_1^*\alpha)$ means $c \wedge \operatorname{pr}_1^*\alpha \in H^6(X \times X', \mathbb{C})$. And how do you push-forward this to get a class in $H^2(X',\mathbb{C})$?

You integrate over the fiber (or cap with the fundamental class of $X\times \{\text{pt}\}$). This is Poincaré dual to the map $\text{pr}_{2*}: H_2(X\times X’)\to H_2(X’)$.

Thank you for the answer! I'm confident about the fact that the map is Poincaré dual to ${\operatorname{pr}2}*$ on the second homology, but I think I don't catch how to write it explicitly. I mean, the fiber of the projection is two dimensional and I should integrate a cocyle in $H^6(X\times X')$, right?

The fiber is real $4$-dimensional, so integrating a $6$-form over the fiber gives a $2$-form on the base.
